# Proving that every basis of a vector space has the same cardinality.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a question concerning following proof, Lemma 1.

http://planetmath.org/allbasesforavectorspacehavethesamecardinality

So, we suppose that A and B are finite and then we construct a new basis $B_1$ for V by removing an element. So they choose $a_1 \in A$ and add it to $S_1$. How do we know for sure that $a_1$ is not yet in B? Can we say this because we suppose that m < n, thus there is certainly such an element?(to derive a contradiction)

Thanks!

Comment: The text seems to be very suspicious - as far as I can tell, the authors seem to  believe that any two infinite sets have the same cardinality.

Comment: Please use single dollar signs \$...\$ for inline math expressions.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Did you see the proof there? They use the [Schröder-Bernstein Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schröder–Bernstein_theorem). I have to read it first...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Which sentence leads you to believe that? The (sound) claim about infinite bases having the same cardinality is the only thing I can see. However, on the same page of the proof of that, I see the author claiming that any two bases of a (finitely generated free) right $R$ module have equal cardinalities, which *is* false... Perhaps the given proof for the infinite version has similar problems.

Comment: It's not exactly on-topic here but the specific problem with the finite-basis proof [here](http://planetmath.org/cardinalitiesofbasesformodules) is that it establishes the set $B$ is finite but fails to establish $|A|=|B|$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't know that. But even if $a_1\in B$, we still have $|(B\setminus\{b_1\})\cup\{a_1\}|\le|B|<|A|$. But your idea to use the assumption $|B|<|A|$ to pick an element of $A$ that is not in $B$ to begin with is also a good way to make the proof work.

Comment: Yes but then $S_1$ would contain two times the same element and every element can only be once in a set, so the set would be 'badly' defined I believe.